# Random password generator issue

Tags: python

I am creating a random password generator but after running the code, when i click on generate password its not showing it on the pop up window although the copy to clipboard is working fine.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import string
import pyperclip

class PasswordGeneratorApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Password Generator")

        self.length_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Password Length:")
        self.length_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=5)
        self.length_entry.insert(0, "12")  # Default length

        self.use_letters_var = tk.IntVar(value=True)
        self.use_numbers_var = tk.IntVar(value=True)
        self.use_symbols_var = tk.IntVar(value=True)

        self.letters_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Include Letters", variable=self.use_letters_var)
        self.numbers_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Include Numbers", variable=self.use_numbers_var)
        self.symbols_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Include Symbols", variable=self.use_symbols_var)

        self.generate_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=self.generate_password)
        self.copy_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Copy to Clipboard", command=self.copy_to_clipboard)

        # GUI Layout
        self.length_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.length_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.letters_checkbox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.numbers_checkbox.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.symbols_checkbox.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.generate_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.copy_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

    def generate_password(self):
        try:
            length = int(self.length_entry.get())
            use_letters = self.use_letters_var.get()
            use_numbers = self.use_numbers_var.get()
            use_symbols = self.use_symbols_var.get()

            characters = ""
            if use_letters:
                characters += string.ascii_letters
            if use_numbers:
                characters += string.digits
            if use_symbols:
                characters += string.punctuation

            if not characters:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select at least one character type.")
                return

            # Generate and return the password
            password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
            return password

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a valid integer for the password length.")
            
    def generate_button_click(self):
        generated_password = self.generate_password()
        if generated_password:
        # Use messagebox.showinfo to display the password string
            messagebox.showinfo("Generated Password", f"Your Password:\n{generated_password}")

    def copy_to_clipboard(self):
        password = self.generate_password()
        if password:
            pyperclip.copy(password)
            messagebox.showinfo("Clipboard", "Password copied to clipboard!")
        else:
            # Handle failure to generate password
            # (e.g., user didn't select any character type)
            pass

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = PasswordGeneratorApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am creating a random password generator but after running the code, when i click on generate password its not showing it on the pop up window although the copy to clipboard is working fine.
It should show the generated password on the pop up window

Comment: Unrelated, but use [secrets.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice) not `random.choice`. The latter is not secure.

Comment: @DillonDavis It doesn't honestly matter very much for this application.

Comment: @AKX until OP decides to generate passwords using their own tool. Granted, its unlikely that someone will fumble through their github for it, but why risk it when its a simple 1-word replacement?

Comment: @DillonDavis It's still not a risk here, since this is an offline tool and there's no practical way for an attacker to have predicted the state of the non-secure PRNG at the point where OP generates their new password (unless they've infiltrated OP's machine, at which point they can just read the clipboard and screen anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not calling the `generate_button_click` on your `generate_button` pressed event. Call the `generate_button_click` instead of `generate_password` method like this:

```
self.generate_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=self.generate_button_click)
```